# how to inherit the width for the for the child of a child

Tags: html, css, position, width, absolute

I have 3 tags: first main `div`, second is a `figure` and inside there is a `figcaption`, like this:

```
<div class="main-div">
  <figure>
    <figcation>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

I assigned the main `div` to be `80%` of the width of the whole document. Then I've set the `figure` to be `100%` of its parent, so it completely wraps around the main `div`.

After that I gave the `figcation` a position of `absolute` and I want it to have `100%` of the width of the main `div` like the `figure`, because its width just runs as the content inside ends.

So how to assign the width for `figcaption` to be the full width of the main `div`?

I tried inheriting but it doesn't work. Also I can't get the `figcaption` tag outside of the `figure` because semantically, that would be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing `position: relative` on one of the `figcaption`'s parent elements `div` or `figure`:

```
figure {
    position: relative;
}

figcaption {
    position: absolute;
}
```

If you use `position: absolute;` the `top|right|bottom|left` values as well as `width` and `height` values like percentages are calculated in relation to the closest parent that doesn't have position `static`. So it's relative to the closest element with position `relative|absolute|fixed` or at last the `html`-element.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/wvf5zoo4/)

Answer (score 0):

Give figure position:relative.

Position absolute need the container to be "positioned".